# How to call service in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How can I call a service like the following in the spring-boot using the RestTemplate class ???

service api : https://192.168.100.20/api/index.php?e=/Base/User/Filter&apikey=a27209c3-edd6-6384-e1cb-1bef2df28&salt=1747229424&signature=JFH44DtCHdSV%2BJBvajNQBsiak07nPVyFb7ZYKj%2BqTno%3D

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work, but I'm not sure what exactly is your goal.

```
private RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
private String url = "https://192.168.100.20/api/index.php?e=/Base/User/Filter&apikey=a27209c3-edd6-6384-e1cb-1bef2df28&salt=1747229424&signature=JFH44DtCHdSV%2BJBvajNQBsiak07nPVyFb7ZYKj%2BqTno%3D";
template.getForEntity(url, String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should try to find is which Http Verb the service you want to call use.
GET, PUT, etc.
When you know which HTTP verb you have to use, you can use RestTemplate with the http verb of your service.

For GET

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String fooResourceUrl =
   "https://192.168.100.20/api/index.php?e=/Base/User/Filter&apikey=a27209c3-edd6-6384-e1cb-1bef2df28&salt=1747229424&signature=JFH44DtCHdSV%2BJBvajNQBsiak07nPVyFb7ZYKj%2BqTno%3D";
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(fooResourceUrl, String.class);
```

For POST

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
 
HttpEntity<Foo> request = new HttpEntity<>(new Foo("bar"));
Foo foo = restTemplate.postForObject(fooResourceUrl, request, Foo.class);
```